# System crashes while inserting CLOB in DB2

Tags: java, db2, spring-jdbc, clob

I am facing this very strange problem from past few days. My application is inserting large size XML(3 MB) into DB2 database. The XML are saved in db as CLOB. Now exactly at the point when the insertion query is executed, my `SYSTEM CRASHES`. The error dump says:

```
DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
```

An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high. This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.

If i modify the code to save an empty string into the CLOB data instead of XML, everything works fine. Another strange thing is that the system does not crashes every time. At times, the application handles 1-2 same requests(same request) successfully and XML data is stored in db. But sometimes, the crash happens at the very first request. I am using Spring-Jdbc. The application is running on a windows machine.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me. Try checking your memory using a tool like `http://www.memtest.org/`. Do you get an error like this at other times as well? And do you have a 2nd machine available to check if the error occurs there as well?

Comment: This issue occurs on every windows machine we are running our application on(i have tried on 3 more machines). On linux, its working fine. I have tried to monitor memory using JProfiler, but i can see quite reasonable available memory at the point when my system crashes. No, i don't get these errors if my application is not running.

Comment: Ok, then forget my mention of memtest. I'd assume some driver incompatibility next - especially if you have machines with shared video memory. But i can't really recommend more than updating drivers and windows patches.

Comment: have you tried a test putting the clob in via the Commandline processor for db2? if that works, you'd know it's related to the spring-jdbc.  also are you using a type 2 or 4 driver?

Comment: Since its working fine on linux, i doubt if its related to Spring-jdbc. We are using type 4 driver.